# Can I refresh parent window through drupal_goto?

Tags: redirection

I am working within iframe but hoping to refresh whole page through drupal_goto. Is it possible to do it ?

Thansk

Answer (score 1):

[drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) will can be used to reload the same window. if you are in iframe, then it will reload the iframe, if you want to refresh the whole page you need javascript and you can add it inline using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

```
  drupal_add_js('parent.location.reload();',array('type' => 'inline'));
```